# What does geh. (geheftet/gehoben) in dictionary definition mean for a word?

Tags: meaning, abbreviation, dictionary

I was looking at the definition of the word Ehegatte in the Oxford German dictionary, and it says

> (geh.) husband

I looked for the definition of `geh.` for a while and it seems to be "geheftet/gehoben". However there isn't any further explanation in addition to that.

Does `geh.` mean the word is used more in a formal, "elevated" setting instead of everyday talk?

Comment: You could trust the list of abbreviations and corresponding explanations provided by the dictionary. Mine provides that prominently on the last page.

Comment: @guidot Sure but I don't find that list easily accessible on the version of Duden and Oxford Dictionary provided by Apple. Can you access those pages on your iPhone/Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually means "gehoben" as you have assumed, so practically *posh*.

Caution: In everyday life, using this kind of vocabulary might make you leave the appearance of a snob.

Comment: Using *Ehegatte* in particular doesn't make you sound like a snob but like a public offical. The posh term is *mein Gatte* or *meine Gattin* instead of *mein Mann* or *meine Frau*. The only time I know of when it is appropriate to use Gatte/Gattin is mocking about being posh.

Answer (score -4):

Geh in Bavarian (Bayerisch) dialect means 'Nicht wahr?' in Hochdeutsch, which means 'Am I right?' or 'Isn't it [so]?' or just 'Right?' in English.  It follows nearly every declarative sentence with a questioning tone.

Comment: a geh, Schmarrn